# Using OOP in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, oop, redux

so i was trying to write a cleaner code, so i decided to create a `Api.js` component and put all my api calls inside it, I passed the response using `OOP` but clearly there has to be a simpler way to do this.
This is my Api component:

```
import axios from 'axios';

class results {

    constructor() {
    }

    success(data) {
        console.log(data)
        return {
            type: 'success',
            data_result: data
        };
    }

    failed(error) {
        console.log(error.status)
        if(error.status == 401){
            alert('page is not found (401)')
        }
        return {
            type: 'error',
            data_result: []
        };
    }

}

class Api extends results {

    constructor(methods, baseUrl, withHeaders, headers) {
        super();
        this.methods = methods;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.withHeaders = withHeaders;
    }

    GET() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            {
                this.withHeaders ?
                    axios[this.methods](`${this.baseUrl}`, this.headers)
                        .then(response => {
                            let finalData = response.data
                            resolve(super.success(finalData))
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            if (error.response) {
                                let finalData = error.response
                                resolve(super.failed(finalData))
                            } else {
                                resolve('network error')
                            }
                        })
                    :
                    axios[this.methods](`${this.baseUrl}`)
                        .then(response => {
                            let finalData = response.data
                            resolve(super.success(finalData))
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            if (error.response) {
                                let finalData = error.response
                                resolve(super.failed(finalData))
                            } else {
                                resolve('network error')
                            }
                        })
            }
        })
    }

}

export const DeclearApi = async (apitools) => {
    const newobj = new Api(apitools.method, apitools.baseurl, apitools.withHeaders, apitools.headers);
    const response = await newobj.GET();
    if (typeof response === 'object') {
        // successful api
        return response;
    }
    else {
        // broken api
        return alert(response)
    }
}
```

And this is the Code i used in my other component that i want to receive data

```
    componentDidMount() {

        //set Api Argument
        const Api = async (tools) => {
            // send
            const ApiCall = await DeclearApi(tools);
            //receive
            if (ApiCall.data_result.length == 0) {
                this.setState({ listCountry: ApiCall.data_result })
            }
            else {
                this.setState({ listCountry: ApiCall.data_result.list })
            }
        }

        Api({
            method: 'get',
            data: false,
            baseurl: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/box/city?bbox=12,32,15,37,10&appid=928d9d03a2b9e90128cd9ade9b048d94',
            headers: false,
            withHeaders: false
        });

    }
```

I wanted to put all my api calls in `Api.js` to simplify and write a cleaner code, but i guess all it had done is made my code more complicated, so is there any alternative ways to do this? and not necessarily with `OOP`, with any method that can make the code simpler and cleaner.

Comment: you can use async await syntax instead of .then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it clearer, you should create a services folder for wrapping your API calls with the backend. since you are using Axios, create a new folder, and call it *services*. then create an HttpService.js as a reusable component of Axios for initializing the connection for future use.

```
// HttpService.js as reusable component 
import axios from "axios"
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, error => {
    const expectedError =
        error.response &&
        error.response.status >= 400 &&
        error.response.status < 500;
    if (!expectedError) {
        console.log("Logging the error", error);
        alert("An unexpected error occurred");

    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
export default {
    get: axios.get,
    post: axios.post,
    put: axios.put,
    delete: axios.delete
};
```

Create a new file in your services folder for your backend call, in my example, I'm doing a **post request** with the user email and password. similarly, you will do a get request for your desired data.

```
// authService.js 
import http from "../services/httpService"
import { apiUrl } from "../../config.json"
const apiEndPoint = apiUrl + "";
export function login(user) {
    return http.post(apiEndPoint, {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
    });
}
```

This is an example of calling the server through the login form component. The **user name and password** were previously set to the state data through the onSubmit handler.

```
import { login } from "../components/services/authService";
// import axios from "axios";
class LoginForm extends Form {
  // username = React.createRef();
  state = {
    data: { email: "", password: "" },
    errors: {},
  };
  doSubmit = async () => {
    // Call server
    try {
      const { data } = this.state;
      await login(data.email, data.password); // Send the login credentials to the API
    } catch (ex) {
      if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 400) {
        const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
        errors.email = ex.response.data;
        this.setState({ errors });
      }
    }

    console.log("Submitted");
  };
}
```

Comment: This is good but you forgot to `await` the `login(...)` call